# How can I re-establish my RAID5 Array (Intel Rapid Storage)?

Tags: motherboard, raid, raid-5, intel-rst

I had a RAID 5 array, but two of the drives dropped from the array. (While troubleshooting another issue ASUS suggested I update my MoBo BIOS, but neglected to tell me this would corrupt my RAID config)

I used a 3rd party piece of software to detect the specifics of my RAID configuration:

```
The array type is RAID5.
The array consists of 3 disks.

The disks are ordered as follows:
#00: Disk 1 - WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0, Serial number WCC4MHDDKCHJ, \\.\PhysicalDrive1
#01: Disk 2 - WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0, Serial number WCC4MPM1HRCE, \\.\PhysicalDrive2
#02: Disk 3 - WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0, Serial number WCC4MEX0JDZK, \\.\PhysicalDrive3

Block size is 64.0 KB , same as 128 sectors.
The data starts at sector (LBA) 0 (this is often called "offset" or "start offset").

Block map is as follows: 
  1  2  P
  3  P  4
  P  5  6
```

Since there were no drive failures or damage (i.e. all the data is physically there), it seems like this is all of the information my MoBo needs to find all the data (perhaps I'm over simplifying this). Is there some way I can re-establish the array without loosing the data?